# Linq and parameters

Tags: c#, linq

I was just wondering what would be more efficient performance wise.  I like reading `values`, while my co-work likes reading `value2`.

```
var values = results.Select(x => new CategoryMixWidgetValueDto
{
    Dimension = x.Dimension, 
    LpeAmount = x.LpeAmount == null ? 0 : double.Parse(x.LpeAmount, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
    BudgetAmount = x.BudgetAmount == null ? 0 : double.Parse(x.BudgetAmount, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
    Variance = x.Variance == null ? 0 : double.Parse(x.Variance, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
})
.Select(x => new CategoryMixWidgetValueDto
{
    Dimension = x.Dimension,
    LpeAmount = x.LpeAmount,
    BudgetAmount = x.BudgetAmount,
    Variance = (x.LpeAmount.DoubleEquals(0) && x.BudgetAmount.DoubleEquals(0)) ? 0 : x.BudgetAmount.DoubleEquals(0) ? null : (x.Variance),
}).ToList();


var values2 = results.Select(x =>
{
    var lpeAmount = x.LpeAmount == null ? 0 : double.Parse(x.LpeAmount, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    var budgetAmount = x.BudgetAmount == null ? 0 : double.Parse(x.BudgetAmount, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    var variance = x.Variance == null ? null : (double?)double.Parse(x.Variance, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    return new CategoryMixWidgetValueDto
    {
        Dimension = x.Dimension,
        LpeAmount = lpeAmount,
        BudgetAmount = budgetAmount,
        Variance = (lpeAmount.DoubleEquals(0) && budgetAmount.DoubleEquals(0)) ? 0 : budgetAmount.DoubleEquals(0) ? null : variance
    };
}).ToList();
```

Comment: Why don't you time it and see which is faster? I would also recommend reading [this](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: Not an answer, but my opinion. I like the second approach. In the first case, you create an array of `CategoryMixWidgetValueDto`, and then recreate a new array **of the same type** but by applying **another logic**. I cannot understand what it does and how it works even after 3 reads. The second approach looks more consistent and logical. It also provides variables which names self-describe its meaning. Moreover, in case 1 you create **twice more objects** which can take up to **twice more memory**.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev There is no intermediate array being created in the first step.  The sequence of items will be processed one at a time, with each one being processed through both Select calls before being collected in the `ToList` at the end.  But two `CategoryMixWidgetValueDto` instances are created for each source object instead of 1, which _does_ add overhead, not to mention the call/return overheads of the `Select` calls.

Answer (score 1):

The second one *should* be more efficient since the first one creates two instances for each source element, and you have two select iterators going on.

However, whether the difference is significant or not depends on your use case. If the number of elements is small, the dto constructor is very light (which it should be), and you're not doing this millions of times in a loop, then you shouldn't see a significant difference.

In my opinion,  since the conversion seems to be somewhat lengthy, you should pull this conversion into a new method, use that inside a select. That way, you can maintain that conversion easier.

```
MyDto GetDto( MyResult resultItem)
{
    ...
}

var dtos = results.Select(GetDto);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the process flow for each version you will see that there are common things that both version do plus things that are unique to one or other.

Here's some pseudo-code of your preferred format:

```
For each item in source:
    Call Select to perform:
        Convert input data types
        Create intermediate object from converted data
    Call Select on intermediate object to perform:
        Do calculations
        Create result object from calculation results
Gather results to new List object
```

And for the second:

```
For each item in source:
    Call Select to perform:
        Convert input data types
        Do calculations
        Create result object from calculation results
Gather results to new List object
```

So your format has an additional call to Select with the overheads that entails, plus an additional object instantiation for the intermediate object.  The second format therefore is more efficient - both in memory and time - because it performs fewer operations, incurs fewer overheads and creates fewer objects.

**However...**

The real question you have to ask though is how much does this inefficiency impact your real-world use case?  Is this a problem for you or is focusing on it just another example of premature optimization?

I did a quick mock of the problem, with 10000 source records processed 100 times (1000000 objects processed in total), counting the outputs rather than putting them into a `List`.  Here are some statistics:

```
Time per item (method A): 3.1616 μs
Time per item (method B): 2.9895 μs
Difference: 172.09 ns
Overhead: ~5.8%
```

Which looks pretty damning, but probably doesn't actually impact your output in the slightest.  The overhead turns out to waste 1 second for every 5.8 **million** input records.

Yes it's generally better to code efficiently.  No, it probably doesn't matter overmuch if the inefficiency you are indulging in can be measured in nanoseconds... unless you are trying to process billions of records, and repeating the process frequently.

Answer (score -1):

The second method is better. Ignoring the real affect, the simple math shows that 1 op < 2 ops (in your case op is allocating object on the heap). Note that there is a big difference when the query is against `IEnumerable<T>` vs `IQueryable<T>` - in the later case the query provider can optimize the execution because everything is expressed as expression tree, while in the former everything executes the way you write it. In other words, `IQueryable` provider could make both variants execute exactly the same way. But that's not the case here.

There is even a special LINQ syntax supporting the second case, which wouldn't be needed if the constructs were fully equivalent:

```
var values2 = (from x in results
    let lpeAmount = x.LpeAmount == null ? 0 : double.Parse(x.LpeAmount, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    let budgetAmount = x.BudgetAmount == null ? 0 : double.Parse(x.BudgetAmount, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    let variance = x.Variance == null ? null : (double?)double.Parse(x.Variance, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    select new CategoryMixWidgetValueDto
    {
        Dimension = x.Dimension,
        LpeAmount = lpeAmount,
        BudgetAmount = budgetAmount,
        Variance = (lpeAmount.DoubleEquals(0) && budgetAmount.DoubleEquals(0)) ? 0 : budgetAmount.DoubleEquals(0) ? null : variance
    }
).ToList();
```

Comment: I don't believe that the second form will produce any noticeable improvement when used on `IQueryable` since the lambda cannot be resolved to an expression tree.  Instead the `IQueryable` will be converted to `IEnumerable` (loading all the records from the data source) before the `Select` is executed.  I think.

Comment: @Corey That was the point (I probably didn't express it right). Queryable provider could make executing the first form to be exactly the same as second. But enumerable (which is the case here) will not.

Comment: Sorry, but that still doesn't make sense to me.